# RxJS operator with array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I think I have a misunderstanding on how works RxJS with an array when I receive it from an HTTP call.

For example I have:

```
  public getNews(): Observable<News[]> {
    return this.http.get<News[]>("/news");
  }
```

And after I want to use a simple map on it:

```
this.newsService.getNews().pipe(map(news => {
    return {
      // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH NEWS
    };
}));
```

The problem is the type of my param, Typescript told me its a array of News but it's inside a map so normally it has to of type News right?

I don't know If I'm clear, but if someone can explain me it would be great :)

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAZEB.png)

Comment: The rxjs operator maps the array to something else. It's not the same as Array#map. You'll want to call Array#map inside the map operator.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the RxJS map operator...it's acting on the *whole* emitted object, an array of News not each item of the news array. Within the RxJS map you can do an array map `news => news.map(singleNews => ({...singleNews, addedProperty: 1}))`. If you clarify what you're aiming for I'll post answer

Comment: @AndrewAllen I understand what you're saying but in the documentation there is this example. They take an array of object and after in the map they have access to the object. And in my case it's still an array. Is it because it come from a request? 

`const source = from([
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Ryan', age: 50 }
]);

const example = source.pipe(map(({ name }) => name));`

[LINK HERE](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map)

Comment: @lud the [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) RxJS operator emits the array as a sequence of values. This (very likely) isn't what you want. You have an array from an api call and within the RxJS map you have a plain array object you can do standard manipulation to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi to convert an array to a list of items you could use the `flatMap` operator; the you can work on each item in the `subscribe` or trasform with `map`

```
this.service.getNews().pipe(
    flatMap(x => x)
).subscribe(x => {
    // do something for each item
});
```

or

```
this.service.getNews().pipe(
    flatMap(x => x),
    map(x => {
    // transform each item
    })
);
```

the second is still an Observable

Comment: it works, so if I understand well, there is a difference between the observable of News[] that http returns and the observable of News[] that flatMap returns?

Comment: well, `flatMap` projects the original observer to a flat list of observers

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `map` operator in `rxjs`'s pipe is operating on the stream of async data, in other words, the `Observable`.

So here, you have an `Observable<News[]>` which means a stream of `New[]`. that means your `this.newsService.getNews().pipe(map(news => {});`'s `news` is an array of `New`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to transform each item inside pipe() you can use:

```
this.getNews()
        .pipe(
            switchMap(newsList => from(newsList)
                .pipe(
                    map(news => {
                        // Do something with each item
                        console.log(news);

                        return news;
                    })
                )
            ),
            // Set back to array
            reduce((curr: NewsData[], next: NewsData) => [...curr, next], []),
        )
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```